# What is the best ASP.NET PDF solution for converting XHTML markup with CSS support?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, pdf, xhtml

I have looked for a good solution for rendering a PDF based on a web page / HTML string, that can also keep the CSS styling.

Does anyone know of any good solutions for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

TRY [ABCPDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm)

I have successffully used in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the free and open source [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) before with some success. I don't think it supports the case where you have a separate .css file, however it does apply inline css you use (the style attribute).

Typically you end up having to create a separate XHTML page for PDF generation with inline styles (and sometimes tables) in order to get the PDF to look right.